# How to use bibliography file with IEEEtransaction?

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

I am in bit of a pickle here. So please help me out. In order to submit my work to IEEE transaction, I downloaded their **IEEEtran.tar** file and unzipped it.

Inside, I started using the **bare_jrnl.tex** file as the basis of my work and started editing it to fit my needs. The content of this file looks like the following (note that, I have removed most of the commented out lines to make the shorter):

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  % \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  % \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate\textbf{•}
\usepackage{url}
\newcommand{\mytilde}{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathtt{\sim}$}}
\newcommand{\DRAFT}{~}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Brown Chicken, Brown Cow!}

\author{xxxxxx,} \linebreak
        yyyyyy} and \linebreak
        zzzzzz.}}% <-this % stops a space

% The paper headers

\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~11, No.~4, December~2012}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Journals}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
dddddd \cite{huston2006}
\end{abstract}

% Note that keywords are not normally used for peerreview papers.
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
ffffff
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}
\input{introduction.tex}

\section{Background}
\label{Background}
\input{background.tex}

\section{Software Implementation}
\label{Software Implementation:}
\input{SoftwareImplementation.tex}

\section{Results}
\label{sec-Results}
\input{Analysis.tex}

\section{Cost Profile}
\label{Cost-Comparison}
\input{CostComparison.tex}

\section{Implementation Analysis}
\label{Implementation-Analysis}
\input{ImplementationAnalysis.tex}

\pagebreak

\section{Conclusion and Future Work}
\label{ConclusionFutureWork}
\input{ConclusionFutureWork.tex}

\appendices
\section{Proof of the First Zonklar Equation}
Appendix one text goes here.

\section{}
Appendix two text goes here.

% use section* for acknowledgement
\section*{Acknowledgment}

The authors would like to thank...

% Can use something like this to put references on a page
% by themselves when using endfloat and the captionsoff option.
\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
  \newpage
\fi

% references section

% can use a bibliography generated by BibTeX as a .bbl file
% BibTeX documentation can be easily obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/
% The IEEEtran BibTeX style support page is at:
% http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% argument is your BibTeX string definitions and bibliography database(s)
%\bibliography{IEEEabrv,../bib/paper}
%
% <OR> manually copy in the resultant .bbl file
% set second argument of \begin to the number of references
% (used to reserve space for the reference number labels box)
%\begin{thebibliography}{1}

%\bibitem{IEEEhowto:kopka}
%H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
%  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.

%\end{thebibliography} 


%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{mySources}


% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

You see in this tex file, I have edited it to fit my needs. And everything works; except 
for the bibliography part. I have created a **.bib** file called **mySources.bib** and placed it in the **same directory** as **bare_jrnl.tex**. Contents of **mySources.bib** look 
something like:

```
@inproceedings{huston2006,
 author               = {G. Huston},
 booktitle            = {Proceedings of APNIC 21},
 month                = {March},
 title                = {{2005 - A BGP Year in Review}},
 year                 = {2006},
 }
```

There are a lot of other references; but I omitted them. Now when I use `\cite{huston2006}`, I only get a **?** instead of reference number. I don't know what
is happening here.

I am using Texmaker 3.3.2 in Windows 7. For **quick build** (in Texmaker), I have used the command: **PdfLatex + Asymptote + PdfLatex + view Pdf**.

After the PDF file is generated with **quick build**, I only get a **?** instead of reference number with the warning: **Citation huston2006 on page 1 undefined**.
Please help me. I don't know, how to fix this mess.

Bye.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Add the compilation step `bibtex` to your Quick Build options. *PdfLatex + Asymptote + BibTeX + PdfLatex + PdfLatex + view Pdf*

Comment: You MUST have a bibliography style. So uncomment `%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`